# How do I programmatically add an apostrophe before and after a string and add a comma inbetween?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I get lists in Outlook, Word or Excel of hundreds of strings like so:

etc.
Currently I run a stored procedure on each of these, in one-by-one fashion.

How could I programmatically add an apostrophe before and after a string and add a comma inbetween, like so: ('','','','','','','')?

I want to change my stored procedure to use IN (' ',' ',' ') and run all of them at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @STRING varchar(max) 
SELECT @STRING = '7864750A 7888801BZ 5189748C 48982572E 6936001F 7096235FG 3218833H'

SELECT '(''' + REPLACE(@STRING,' ',''',''') + ''')'
```

gives this result:

```
('7864750A','7888801BZ','5189748C','48982572E','6936001F','7096235FG','3218833H')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a table-valued UDF that takes the strings as input and returns the items in separate rows of a table.  Something like this (not the most efficient thing in the world...):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitMyValues]
(
    @Input VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    Data VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Where   INT
    DECLARE @Length  INT
    DECLARE @Next    INT

    SET @Where  = 0
    SET @Length = LEN(@Input)

    WHILE (@Where < @Length)
    BEGIN
        SET @Next = CHARINDEX(' ', @Input, @Where)

        IF (@Next > 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (SUBSTRING(@Input, @Where, @Next - @Where))
            SET @Where = @Next + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (SUBSTRING(@Input, @Where, LEN(@Input)))
            SET @Where = @Length
        END
    END

    RETURN
END
```

To see the output, you can just run this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.SplitMyValues('7864750A 7888801BZ 5189748C 3218833H')
```

Then you can just do a join or a subquery in the `WHERE` clause of an `UPDATE` or `SELECT`, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   SomeTable S
   INNER JOIN dbo.SplitMyValues('7864750A 7888801BZ 5189748C 3218833H') X
     ON X.Data = S.WhateverColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick I use from time to time on excel data...

Supposing there are several rows of data in columns A and B starting on the 2nd row.
I'll go to cell C2 and place a string formula in there.

```
="INSERT INTO MyTable(X, Y) SELECT '" & A2 & "', '" & B2 & "'"
```

which evaluates to

INSERT INTO MyTable(X, Y) SELECT 'AValue', 'BValue'

Then I copy and paste that down the C column... relative cell references take care of the rest.

PS: Watch out for nulls!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use find and replace all instances of " " with " ',' " , and then add " (' " at the beginning and " ') " at the end.